# VS2013 conversion breaks VS2012 Silverlight Project

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Working VS2012 Solution.
Components:

Silverlight Project.

Web Application Project.
 The web application project houses a wcf service. The service is consumed by the Silverlight project.

In the Silverlight project, Object Browse the  service Reference. All is well. Full list of exposed objects.

Open solution in VS2013.
Conversion occurs with no errors and no warnings except that non functional changes are being made.

Browse the Service reference. It now shows only one class and the Silverlight project is broken as all its references to the service objects  are missing. Deleting and renewing the service reference has no effect.

Add a dummy Silverlight project to the solution and add a service reference. Object browse this reference and it is OK.

Anyone struck anything similar? Is there a special procedure for migrating Silverlight projects?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this myself. It turns out that the Silverlight project that I was migrating targets the Silverlight version 4 runtime, which has reached the end of its product lifecycle. You will need to upgrade your application to target the version 5 runtime before migrating the solution to VS2013.

For reference, here are the [SDKs that are supported by VS2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn250998.aspx) out of the box, as well as the  [Silverlight Product Support Lifecycles](http://support2.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-us&c2=12905).